# jQuery: 'async: false' Not Working With IE7 / IE6

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I created a simple tracking script which adds the users info to a database when the page is unloaded. It works on all browsers except IE7 and IE6.

IE7 gives me errors, but I can't open the "debugger" because I'm using the standalone version (or at least that's what I think the problems is). I removed the `async: false,` from the script below and I didn't get any errors, but I need async set to false in order for the script to work. Any ideas?

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "add.php",
    data: "ip=" + jIp + "&date=" + jDate + "&time=" + jTime,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has the following line:

```
data: "ip=" + jIp + "&date=" + jDate + "&time=" + jTime,
```

This code is broken in IE6/7, because there is a trailing comma in the object literal's property list. This is arguably legal Javascript, but is the source of no end of IE-specific errors. Remove the last comma and your call will work.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thank you both for the prompt replies!

Answer (score 1):

The comma at the end of this line, or just a typo in the post?

> data: "ip=" + jIp + "&date=" + jDate +
>   "&time=" + jTime,